# Flex swf Application doesn't start in Firefox/Chrome but works perfectly in Internet Explorer

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, flash

I have an issue with a Flex application which cannot be loaded in Firefox or Chrome, but works perfectly in Internet Explorer.

I first thought it might be an issue with the embedding in the HTML page, but even if I load the swf url alone without the html page it does not work. But here comes the crazy thing. When I now save this loaded swf to my local harddrive and drag this swf file in chrome or fireofx it works.

I even tried the Adobe SWF Investigator but I cannot find an issue in the swf.

Does anybody know whether there is an isssue with Flash Player 11.7 and Firefox 21 or Chrome 27?

The application itself is build with Flex 3.

Here is an URL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhnovyslcfraxde/perforce_client.swf

Best regards,
Christian

-----------8<---------------------------------------------------------------------------

update: right click and play in the flash menu started the application.

crazy!!

-----------8<---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Probable a cached version with an error. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Are you using the debug Flash player? I get a stack trace about when I run the SWF. It seems like your code handles the error, though, as I also get a dialog box from your app w/the error. Silly suggestion, I know, like the above suggestion, but it can't hurt to confirm that you're using the debug Flash player in Firefox and Chrome -- note there are 3 separate Flash plugins in this case: the ActiveX plugin for IE, Chrome's built in plugin, and then the old school "Netscape" style plugin for every other browser.

Comment: @RIAstar: I have cleared the cache and I also tried it from different computers, but it did not work.

Comment: @SunilD.: I have used the debug flash player for ie, firefox and chrome. this was not the issue.

Comment: we did find out that pressing play on the movie did help (right click on the swf application and select play in the flash menu). this is really crazy. i never had an issue like this in 7 years of flex development experience. does anybody know if there is an issue for netscape style plugin with flex 3 applications which do not start automatically?

Answer (score 0):

For over than a year I faced the same problem, I inevitably have to use the IE as the main browser. But one day when I entered "chrome:// plugins" into Chrome browser, I found there are two Flex Player (FP) plugins there, one of which is a non debugger FP that comes with the Chrome Browser and the other is a debugger FP which is automatically installed by Adobe Flex, I think this is the problem. So I disable the first flash player plugin and let the debugger flash player continues to work, and wow ... Chrome can debug flex now !